# I am able to pick only the Gallery image or photo but not going to the camera and clicking image in flutter. Please fix my issue

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I am able to only the Gallery image  or photo but not going to the camera and clicking image in flutter. Please fix my issue
Here is my code

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    r
              child: Text('Select the Device Photo',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26),),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      _imagePosition = 0;
                      getGallery();
                      getCamera();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 184,
                      height: 180,
                      child: Card(
                          child: (_imageList[0].path != '')
                              ? Image.file(_imageList[0], fit: BoxFit.fill,)
                              : Icon(Icons.add_photo_alternate,
                              size: 130, color: Colors.grey[700])
                      ),),
                  ),
                ),
              
               
              ],
            ),
          ),
   ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  
  Future getGallery() async {
    // Get image from gallery.
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      _cropImage(image);
    });


  }
  Future getCamera() async {
    // Get image from Camera.
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      _cropImage(image);
    });

  
  }
```

I want to pick Image from Gallery and camera and save into sqlite. Everything is working fine i.e my gallery image is saving but not picking image from camera.

Comment: why are you adding both getGallery(); and  getCamera(); under same tap event. How can you open Gallery and Camera view at the same time?

Comment: Ok Please suggest me How to fix my Issue  with the code. You are absolutely right.At a time either I will chose Gallery or Image . Not both at a time.

Comment: You have made it a lot complicated, simply add two different buttons for gallery and camera.

Comment: ASAD HAMEED can you help me on that functionality as I have to save or store into sqlite  further  and  be able to se the details and Delete too in future.

Comment: Actaully Iam following"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gksxBDR87o"   by replacing with my variables or values .  I am getting the follwoing after picking imge from galley or camera.

Comment: Yes Now I have implemented selction Option to chose Gallery or Camera but my when I capture with Camera It is crashing, with black screen   with the following errors    I/Timeline(16820): Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:54370667 intent:Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE    And saying as          W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16820): reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection
Lost connection to device.
          and in the device saying as "path" i.e the image path should not be null

Comment: any body who has worked on it, please share your suggestions or code here.